# Excel: Narrow entries from a sheet to those that appear on another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a relatively novice Excel user trying to streamline the following task:

I've got two sheets of product information. Sheet1 has around 3000 entries and Sheet2 has around 1300 entries. Every SKU in the product number column on Sheet2 appears on Sheet1, but some are formatted differently: some cells in Sheet1's SKU column occasionally contain multiple comma-separated entries (Example: PDB2S2FW, PDB2S2V, PDB2S2WH), whereas all Sheet2 SKUs are listed in their own cells.

My goal is to identify the items on Sheet 1 that appear on Sheet2 (with a filter or a helper column) so that I can narrow down Sheet1 to include only the items on Sheet2.

I've been experimenting with a few formulas to attempt this task, but haven't been able to solve for the multiple entry/single cell issue.

Here's my current formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(BJ9,Sheet2!B:B,0)),"Not found","Found")
```

[Column BJ on Sheet1 and Column B on Sheet2 hold product numbers.]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses an array formula. If you're new to Excel, you may not know how to do an array formula, so I'll add a quick tutorial and a link at the end of this answer:

This formula will give you a zero if there is not a match and a positive number if there is a match. Enter the formula in a column next to BJ on Sheet1, then drag fill to the bottom. You can then filter out all positive numbers and see those values which are not found on Sheet2.

**Assumption:** Values start in Row 1. If they don't, change $BJ1 to match the row where values start.

```
{=LARGE(IFERROR(FIND($BJ1,Sheet2!$B:$B),0),1)}
```

**Note:** It might be more efficient if you change `Sheet2!$B:$B` to reference only the cells that actually have data, instead of the entire column. For example: `Sheet2!$B$1:$B:$3000`.

**Array Formulas**

To enter the array formula,

- Select and copy the above formula *excluding the curly braces*. The curly braces are there just to show that it is an array formula.
- Paste the formula into a cell on your spreadsheet.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[This page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7) has more info about array formulas.

**Caveat**

The `IFERROR` function is only available in later versions of Excel. If you're using an older version, you may need to work with `ISERR` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! The formula is still not picking up every entry, and is creating some false positives and inconsistencies.

Examples:

Sheet 1, column BJ entry: V2410B, 2410B-FW, 2410B-BK, 2410B-WH

Sheet 2, column B entries:
V2410A
V2410B
V2410C
V2410DFO
V2410FC

Result of formula: 0
---

Sheet 1, Column BJ entry: 630B
Sheet 2, Column B entries:
630B
630BDK
630C
630CDK

Formula result: 8

Comment: I should have expected false positives. You will have false positives if one number is a substring of another number. For example, if V2630B is a valid number in Sheet1, 630B in Sheet2!BJ will register as found. The false negatives, however, are surprising. Hmm.

Comment: I don't know if you can do this using a formula. Have you considered trying VBA?

Comment: *Sheet 1, column BJ entry: V2410B, 2410B-FW, 2410B-BK, 2410B-WH Sheet 2, column B entries: V2410A V2410B V2410C V2410DFO V2410FC Result of formula: 0*  Given that list, the only problem I see is that the first entry (V2410B) is not being found. The remaining entries are not in the list and shouldn't be found.

Comment: The other way I'm considering doing this is by building a helper column on Sheet2 next to the SKU column and using the index function to copy rows for matching values on the larger sheet. Seems a little more straightforward, since all entries in the SKU column on Sheet2 are single entries, none of those pesky multiple-entry cells. Just not completely sure how to do that.

Comment: Basically, I want to figure out how to 1) find which rows on Sheet1 contain SKUs that match each Sheet2 SKU entry, then 2) copy those Sheet1 rows in their entirety onto either Sheet2 or a new sheet.